# How to use tesseract in android studio?

Tags: android, macos, ant, android-ndk, tesseract

I have been trying to build a mobile application which needs the usage of tesseract-OCR.

I have downloaded the android ndk as well

I have cloned the necessary 'Tessdata' and 'tess-two' and 'eyes-two' solders from https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two .
I have been struggling with the ndk-build and the ant release to get tesseract running on my mac yosemite.

For the 'ant' command to work, I have downloaded apache-ant-1.9.6 as well.

I'm not able to build-ndk and use ant after multiple tryouts.

Comment: hi it isnt building with ndk and ant command isnt working even after the apache set up from the command line.

Comment: "android update project --path" in this command, 'android' command is not found!

Comment: run the command with **your_sdk_path/tools/android update project --path**

Comment: thank you so much @boss i got it running.